# How are Javascript functions processed if invoked again before current invocation completes?

Tags: javascript

This is a question concerning how JavaScript functions are processed if invoked again before completion and the relation to indexedDB operations. It's nothing especially profound or special but just new to me.

Please consider a web page with an associated indexedDB database that has buttons `prev` and `next` that step through the records in the database by retrieving the appropriate data from the object stores, building the HTML in a document fragment, adding the necessary event listeners, and then appending the fragment to the document.

All my test examples take place quite quickly, but what would occur if a user clicked the `next` button rapidly multiple times in quick succession and the entire process was invoked again before it fully completed?  Would the program fail or would the record associated with the final click be displayed without error?

I don't exactly understand what I'm attempting to ask here but will all the invocations sort of accumulate on the stack and process in order, and as events are fired/triggered?

Is some form of protection against this situation necessary, such as below using variable `busy`, to prevent the process from starting again before reaching completion?

Thank you.

```
function get_new_record()
  {
    if ( get_new_record.busy ) return;
    get_new_record.busy = true;
    ...

   transaction.oncomplete  = function()
     { 
       build_HTML();
       add_event_listeners();
       append_to_DOM();
       get_new_record.busy = false;
     };
  }
```

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. The database queries can run concurrently, but once a response is returned to one of the event listeners, all the code in the `oncomplete` function will run uninterrupted.

Comment: Thank you.  Does this mean that a second button click can't "re-start" get_next_record mid-process, but must wait for the synchronous portion of it to complete?

Comment: Each click starts a new `get_new_record()`. These each issue a query, which runs asynchronously. When one of the queries completes, it runs the `oncomplete` function. Other queries will wait for that to finish before their `oncomplete` functions start.

Comment: Thank you.  I think understand. So that is a problem because it appears that in this multiple-rapid-click scenario it would be possible for a later click to a record that had little or no data to complete before an earlier click of a record that had a lot of data.

Comment: Yes, there's no guarantee that requests will complete in the same order that the user clicked on them. If you need to ensure this ordering, you'll need to do something like your `busy` variable. Another option is to display a "Loading" indicator that blocks clicks.